# Why am I getting nonsense like $\bmod 3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{a+x:x=3\}$ when trying to apply quotient ring definition in an example?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having difficulty applying the following quotient ring definition in an example.

Definition: Let $I$ be an ideal in a ring $R$. Then $$R/I=\{[a]_I:a\in R\}$$ where $[a]_I=\{a+x:x\in I\}=\{b\in R:b\equiv a\pmod I\}. \tag{$*$}$

Now consider, say, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{Z}=R$ and $3\mathbb{Z}=\langle 3\rangle=I$. We have $$\mathbb{Z}_3=\{[a]_{\langle 3 \rangle} : a \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$ Then using the definition gives $$[a]_{\langle 3\rangle}=\{a+x:x\in\mathbb{3z}\}=\{b\in\mathbb{Z}:b\equiv a\mod 3\mathbb{Z}\}.$$ But that doesn't seem to make much sense with the $\mod3\mathbb{Z}$ part. I don't understand why that didn't work and I might instead be tempted to write $$[a]_{\langle 3\rangle}=\{a+x:x\in 3\mathbb{Z}\}=\{a+3y:y\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{b\in\mathbb{Z}:b\equiv a\pmod 3\}=[a]_{3}$$ but this would give $\{a+x:x=3\}$ by $(*)$. Clearly I've got myself into a muddle and would appreciate any help clarifying why it is that I can't get the definition to work here.

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod {3\mathbb Z}$ is just a verbose way of saying what you used to called $a\equiv b\pmod 3$. That is, before you said $a\equiv b\pmod 3$ if $a-b$ is divisible by $3$, which is the same as $a-b\in 3\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle3\rangle$, not $<3>$. I changed it. Note that you don't get proper spacing in $A=<3>$ whereas you do in $A=\langle3\rangle. \qquad$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh I see, thanks! What about the last line though - why do I get $[a]_{3}=\{a+x:x=3\}$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh my bad! Many thanks.

Comment: @Alex.F Honestly, I don't know why you get that, and I am having trouble guessing how you arrived at such a strange expression.  Could you explain more about the steps you took to get $[a]_3 = \{a+x: x=3\}$ starting from (*)?

Comment: @Alex.F Speculation: you are conflating the ideal notation $\langle 3\rangle$ with the set notation $\{3\}$ and interpreting $x \in \langle3\rangle$ as $x \in \{3\}$ which is equivalent to $x=3$.

Comment: @ErickWong So I arrived at $[a]_3$ with the last equation and then substituted $3=I$ into $(*)$ but that's where I've gone wrong, I think. $[a]_{\langle3\rangle}=[a]_{3}$ but $I=\langle3\rangle \neq 3$, right?

Comment: @Alex.F Ah ok, well you see... $3$ is not an ideal.  So it doesn't make sense to apply the definition of $[a]_I$ to the notation $[a]_3$.  Since you introduced the expression $[a]_3$ I assume you already know what it means: there's no reason to apply this new ideal-based definition to an existing symbol.

Comment: @ErickWong Oops I meant to write $x\in 3$ rather than $x=3$ but yeah that makes sense. I'm not sure why I thought that in hindsight. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing some of the comments into an answer:

As ThomasAndrews points out, there is nothing wrong with the notation $\pmod{3\mathbb Z}$: it is just a synonym for the simpler notation $\pmod 3$.  This more long-winded way of saying the same thing has the advantage of extending the reach of the "modulo" concept to a vastly more general setting, that of ideals in rings.  This was a key concept in the development of algebraic number theory, particularly in early work on Fermat's Last Theorem by Kummer.

For the second part of your question, it appears that you are taking the definition of $[a]_I$ where $I$ is an ideal, and applying it to interpret the notation $[a]_3$.  However, this doesn't make sense for two reasons: 1) because $3$ is not an ideal so the definition doesn't apply, and 2) because $[a]_3$ already has a definition (which you supplied in the OP), so there is no reason to force a new one upon it.  The notation $[a]_I$ generalizes the simpler notation $[a]_n$ (where $n$ is a natural), but it is not meant as a *literal* replacement (it makes no attempt to supersede the existing definition of $[a]_n$).  Much like the above, you can think of $[a]_{3\mathbb Z}$ as a more verbose but also more flexible way to express the concept of $[a]_3$.

In some sense the heart of ideal theory is the realization that not every ideal can be thought of as just multiples of a single number, so there is actually value in **not** abbreviating the ideal $3\mathbb Z$ as just $3$.  You could, however, equivalently write it as $\langle 3 \rangle$, with the understanding that the angle brackets can admit multiple values, and that the same ideal might have multiple such representations (so it is not a canonical way to describe an ideal).